# Complex Pattern Match

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I've been wrapping my head around this, including trying something outside regex, I need two to regex that matches this

```
'Name in "{Name1, Name2}"' and  'Name in "(Name1, Name2)"'
```

More exactly that matches both 'Name' and 'Name1, Name2', being Name, Name1 and Name2 any combination of words and spaces.

This is what I had

```
'(\\b)(\\s)in(\\s)\\\"{.+?}\\\"'
```

Comment: so you need to match any `Name` plus some probable numbers?

Comment: If you're not so good with regex, I'd recommend shying away from this approach.  Better to parse the String into a csv list and tokenize that to get names.

Comment: @duffymo no i need regex agility for this, already found a why. Don't discourage people, unless you are certain of a better aprouch. :/

Comment: I am certain of a better approach.  It's not discouraging anybody to advise them to think about something different.  Ever heard this?  "You have a problem.  You decide to use regex to solve it.  Now you have two problems."  It applies when "not so good with regex".

Answer (score 1):

Here, we might be able to write an expression to cover both cases using capturing groups. Maybe similar to this:

```
([})])?([A-Z][a-z]+)?([0-9]+)?(,\s)?([({])?
```

[image]

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "([\\})])?([A-Z][a-z]+)?([0-9]+)?(,\\s)?([(\\{])?";
final String string = "{Name1, Name2}\n"
     + "(Name1, Name2)";
final String subst = "\\2";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /([})])?([A-Z][a-z]+)?([0-9]+)?(,\s)?([({])?/gm;
const str = `{Name1, Name2}
(Name1, Name2)`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/koJcWq/1). You can reduce the boundaries and much simplify this expression for instance.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

Comment: What’s the point of all these optional groups? What’s the advantage over just searching for `[A-Z][a-z]+`?

Answer (score -1):

Found a way to do this by using two regex, one too match the whole thing a other to seperate them first using this '\w+\s\S+?\s+\"([^\"]*)\"'